# My bluetooth is not turning on

Tags: bluetooth

I have just installed Ubuntu for the first time

I cant get my bluetooth to turn on.

I ran a couple of commands and these are the results:

`$ sudo rfkill list`

```
 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`$ sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth`
`$ sudo rfkill list`

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`$ dmesg | grep Blue`

```
[   16.575002] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   16.575014] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   16.575016] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   16.575018] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   16.575021] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   19.060274] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   27.056612] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Reading local version info failed (-110)
[   27.061648] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   27.077663] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM43142A
[   27.077667] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   27.535077] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   34.933334] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   34.933337] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   34.933341] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

`$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb`

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 064e:930a Suyin Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: You need to get that `BCM.hcd` file for your adapter.